# change the height of statusStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, statusstrip

I have a simple windows form with a statusStrip in VS2010, and no matter what I tried, the height of statusStrip does not change, what is proper way of changing the height??

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just changed the StatusStrip size without problems...

- Create a new Form.
- Create a StatusStrip.
- Set its property "Dock" to "None".
- Set its property "Autosize" to "False".
- Set its property "Size" with Height = 'the height you need' (I have put it to 100).
- If you want, now you can Dock to "Bottom" again.
- Add a ProgressBar: it will be 100 Height.

Let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 0):

None of the mentioned approaches worked. Eventually this is the working solution for us:

First, use a TableLayoutPanel with a row at 100% and bottom row with absolute height of 24 (or any desired height you want).

Second, drag and drop the ToolStrip control into the bottom row, and setting the Dock property to Fill. This forces the ToolStrip control to fill the bottom cell of the TableLayoutPanel. Now you have a toolstrip with height 24.