# c# Unable to set the size of the ToolStripStatusLabel?

Tags: c#, statusstrip, toolstripstatuslabel

In the toolstripstatuslabel, I'm adding images and displaying it as shown below.

Case 1: Setting the image list size [Not working]

Case 2: Setting the size of the label.[Not working]

In both the above cases, size is not getting reflected.

```
StatusStrip statusStrip = new StatusStrip();
//Set the size of the status bar
statusStrip.AutoSize = false;

ImageList imgList = new ImageList(); 

...Add resource images to image list

imgList.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);

//Set the images on the status strip
ToolStripStatusLabel add = new ToolStripStatusLabel();
add.Image = jobImgList.Images[0];

//Set auto size to false, so specify the size
add.AutoSize = false;
add.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);

statusStrip.Items.Add(add);
```

Is there any other property that needs to be changed other than setting AutoSize to false!?

Comment: And also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216308/change-the-height-of-statusstrip/9191268#9191268

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as simple as that!

`statusStrip.ImageScalingSize = new Size(40, 40);`

Reference: 
[How to increase the size of the buttons on a tool strip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432025/how-to-increase-the-size-of-the-buttons-on-a-tool-strip)